# rails json response not able to build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a method in controller creat

it respond generate array of records like

```
[{"code"=>500, "body"=>{"message"=>"Ivalid data or you enter a duplicate data"}}, {"code"=>200, "body"=>{"id"=>"775606be-d3ae-4b43-a820-74022f8f273f"}}, {"code"=>500, "body"=>{"message"=>["Name has already been taken"]}}, {"code"=>500, "body"=>{"message"=>[:Error, ["No Fable", "level not found in rand", "Invalid or Blank e"]]}}]
```

now I want to make it n a json response

```
def create
   k=[{"code"=>500, "body"=>{"message"=>"Ivalid data or you enter a duplicate data"}}, {"code"=>200, "body"=>{"id"=>"775606be-d3ae-4b43-a820-74022f8f273f"}}, {"code"=>500, "body"=>{"message"=>["Name has already been taken"]}}, {"code"=>500, "body"=>{"message"=>[:Error, ["No Federation ID in Cookie ID\n# Mapping Table", "level not found in Brand", "Invalid or Blank Source Type"]]}}]
    # render create.json.jbuilder
    render json: k, status: 200
  end
```

so it generate

```
{
  "bulks": [
    {
      "code": 500,
      "body": {
        "message": "Ivalid data or you enter a duplicate data"
      }
    },
    {
      "code": 200,
      "body": {
        "id": "7754322222222f"
      }
    },
    {
      "code": 500,
      "body": {
        "message": [
          "Name has already been taken"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "code": 500,
      "body": {
        "message": [
          "Error",
          [
            "No Fable",
            "level not found in Brand",
            "Invalid or Blank Source Type"
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
```

}

it added `bulks:` while render the json in controller

how can I remove the `bulks` the expected json would be

```
{   {
          "code": 500,
          "body": {
            "message": "Ivalid data or you enter a duplicate data"
          }
        },
        {
          "code": 200,
          "body": {
            "id": "775606be-d3ae-4b43-a820-74022f8f273f"
          }
        },
        {
          "code": 500,
          "body": {
            "message": [
              "Name has already been taken"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "code": 500,
          "body": {
            "message": [
              "Error",
              [
                "No Fable",
                "level not found in Brand",
                "Invalid or Blank Source Type"
              ]
            ]
          }
        } }
```

Please help

Comment: The response comes from ActiveRecord or are you building the json ?

Comment: not active record but a static json

Comment: You're right. Funny is, if I do the same here, I got no root `bulk`

Comment: `as_json `root false I tried but it gave `root too` bulk

Comment: And what about `render json: k, root: false, status: 200` ? Using the root: false option of the `render` method

Comment: same no hope :( I solved it by using jbuilder